Prove that if $P_{1},\dots,P_{m} \in L(V)$ are projectors such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m}P_{i} = I$, then $V = R(P_{1}) \oplus \dots \oplus R(P_{m})$
This was asked in our problem sheet. I tried for good amount of time but couldn't prove it.
Let projection operators $P_{1},\dots,P_{m} \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $V$ is finite dimensional vector space such that $P_{1} + \dots + P_{m}$ is the identity operator. Prove that $V = R(P_{1}) \oplus \dots \oplus R(P_{m})$ where $R(P_{i})$ denotes the range space of $P_{i}$
Note : There was no field mentioned in my problem sheet. But we usually deal with only $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.
MY APPROACH
I was able to prove it for $m=2$ and was trying to generalize for any $m$. To prove that it's a direct sum, I have to prove that if $x_{1} + \dots + x_{m} = 0$, then $\forall \: i=1,2,\dots,m : x_{i} = 0$.
So we have
\begin{align*}
x_{1} + \dots + x_{m} = 0
\end{align*}
Applying $P_{1}$ we get
\begin{align*}
P_{1}x_{2} + \dots + P_{1}x_{m} = -x_{1}
\end{align*}
and using the fact that it is identity operator, I will have $P_{2}x_{1} + P_{3}x_{1} + \dots + P_{m}x_{1} = 0$. From here I can't move ahead.

I've tagged this as a duplicate, assuming you understand the trace of an idempotent matrix gives its rank e.g. of a field of characteristic zero.  You do not state the field but the problem statement is not true in general; e.g. with $m=4$ and all projectors $=I$ with a field of characteristic 3, so you must be making field assumptions

I had a look at the post you shared. As per my understanding, there each $A_{i}$ is symmetric but here we are given that $P$ are not symmetric by they are only idempotent. Sorry that I didn't add any field because it was not mentioned in my problem sheet. Basically you can assume that field of vector space if real or complex. I am editing the question also

Re-read the two answers in the link.  Neither of them make use of symmetry as it is irrelevant to the problem.

To be clear what my answer in the link shows is $P_jP_k = \mathbf 0$ for $j\neq k$.  This means they commute.  You can finish in a granular way if you want but for a succinct finish: simultaneously diagonalize all the $P_i$.

I got the idea of what you are saying. One thing here is that in this problem we are given that each $P$ is projector and we have to prove that their rank add up to $\dim V$.

right -- that's why the first sentence of my original comment says "... assuming you understand the trace of an idempotent matrix gives its rank..."

Thanks for reply. I got the idea. We know that $I = P_{1} + \dots + P_{m}$,  applying trace we will get $\dim V = \text{rank}(P_{1}) + \dots + \text{rank}(P_{m})$ and we also know that $V = R(P_{1}) + \dots + R(P_{m})$ implies it forms a direct sum.
